# How to display logged in users comments (only) on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm currently building a niche Q+A site using wordpress with which users can either log in and post questions or log in and answer questions.

Questions are currently being stored as posts, and answers stored as comments. I want question answerers to be able to log in and view all their comments (answers) on one page with a link to the original post (question).

I can easily list posts in this way (i.e. list all of the logged in users posts on one page i.e. their original questions) but cant seem to do this with comments (i.e. list all the logged in user's answers on one page.) Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on *Settings* > *Discussions* and set what you want from there. There is one option that lets only registered members to post a comment.
2. http://pastebin.com/EJcghXAW - see code from line #39, same aproach also in your case.

The query for the comments is the normal wordpress way, but you need to include it in the conditionals linked and pointed above.

**Usage example:**

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $args = array(
        'status' => 'approve',
        'order' =>  'DESC',
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
        echo '<p>'; 
        echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
        echo '</p>';
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how this allows me to display all of a logged in users comments on one page (a page without any other content) i.e. if a user is logged in and clicks on a page entitled my comments it display all his/her comments (that relate to multiple posts) in one place? (apologies if this should be obvious)

Comment: <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
} ?> - so, you make a query getting all comments by user id ($user_id) -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments see the latest integer in the list user_id 
    (integer) The comment author's ID if s/he is registered (0 otherwise) and also examples :)

Comment: <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $args = array(
     'status' => 'approve',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
     echo '<p>'; 
     echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content);
        echo '</p>';
    endforeach;
}
?>

Comment: Added example in my answer. Let me know if you can succeed :)

Comment: I've just tried it and it worked like a charm, thanks so much man, this has been bugging me for days, your a hero!!!

Comment: Omg! :) Not a hero, just a developer who has been helped here by other and now trying to help others also. Glad that you have been succeeded. When you'll have other WP questions posted, you can pm me also.

Comment: But a vote up and an answer acceptance I would accept instead of being a hero :P