# Show logged in users comments with post title of post

Tags: wordpress, comments

This thread [How to display logged in users comments (only) on Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009734/how-to-display-logged-in-users-comments-only-on-wordpress)
has gotten me most of the way to where I want to be... However, I am trying to change it slightly so that instead of the author's name it displays the post title and links back to the post they left the comment on.

This is the code I've come up with but it is not working.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
  $user_id = get_current_user_id(); $args = array( 'status' => 'approve', 'order' =>    'DESC', 'user_id' => $user_id ); 
  $comments = get_comments($args); foreach($comments as $comment) : echo '<p>'; 
  $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
  $member_name = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );

  echo( '<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID );">' . $member_name . '</a><br />' . $comment->comment_content); 
  echo '</p>'; 
  endforeach; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not where I can test this, but you’re grabbing the post into the array $member_name. So to display the post name, replace the output $member_name with $member_name->post_title.

Like:

```
echo( '<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID );">' . $member_name->post_title . '</a><br />' . $comment->comment_content);
```

Probably could rename the array to something clearer like $post also.

Comment: that helped to get rid of the error... now I am trying to figure out why my url has php in it when though.

Comment: I figured it out... this is what the code should have been the whole time!
   
    echo ( '<a href="' . get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '">' . $member_name->post_title . '</a><br />' . $comment->comment_content);

Comment: Yep, sorry wasn’t focused on that part of the statement only the title part.

Comment: That's fine. I am having a different problem now that relates to this but I am not sure if it should be going in a new thread.... I followed the steps in this article: https://www.cssigniter.com/add-rating-wordpress-comment-system/ to add a star rating to the comments system... but when I list the comments with the code above the stars are not showing up I have tried what seems like a million things and I can not seem to figure out why the stars are not showing up.

Comment: That should be a new question since it isn't related to the current question.

Comment: Thanks, Mark after more thought I realized that it was actually a completely unrelated question.... I just posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093019/show-star-ratings-in-comments